No response after initiating the notice
I am working as a Senior IT Developer in one of the big organizations. Due to the office politics, I decided to switch and got another offer.

So I requested my manager for one-one meeting and informed them that I had received another opportunity and decided to move forward with it.
Then I initiated the notice by mail with the "last date". (Because here the notice needs to be sent to the direct leader, HR will not be directly involved, when I confirmed this process with the HR and they said the same).

Then after 6 days, I checked with my manager for 'Did HR respond back?' via communicator in text and He read the message but he is not responding back. I am not sure what is happening?
I still have only 3 more days for my last date.
Could someone help me in taking it forward? I am really afraid something has gone wrong.

Contact HR yourself. Go in person if possible

What country are you in? In the UK, you've clearly resigned and it's the company's problem now. But with all due respect: waiting until the 23rd December to worry about this was not a good plan.

@Donald,
I reached HR via portal and they mentioned your manager will take care of it. now I am confused on the next steps

@PhilipKendall, I am from USA and I reached HR via portal and they mentioned your manager will take care of it. now I am confused on the next steps

When you told HR had not yet confirmed the fact you resigned? It is a holiday in the US, so ask them what the next steps are, or what those would be.

If HR has confirmed your last work date, the next step is that you work the notice period as assigned, which if your manager has a clue will typically be spent on transferring as much of your knowledge as possible to whoever will be picking up your tasks. If your manager doesn't tell you to do that, it would be a nice gesture to take the initiative and do so anyway. Leaving around this time of year, when people are thoroughly distracted and often burning off vacation, is generally going to be awkward; you just have to deal with it as best you can.

@Donald, I informed HR that I sent the mail to my manager leaving two weeks notice and HR said its good and mentioned that manager will take care of it.

@keshlam I am restless, not sure what is the process to return the laptop and what to do on the last day, Getting slight heart attack

@Harry - We really can’t help you. In 3 days you should assume your resignation was accepted and even if it wasn’t, in the US, it’s also unnecessary in many cases. Just show up to your new job. Place the laptop in a box, ship it to the office, or even better hand it to your supervisor.

Wait - so you sent notice by postal mail?    Please clarify

@Harry: make sure you have proof of resignation. Did you send this my registered mail? Did have a receipt that you sent it (either electronically or paper) , Make sure you log any communication with your manager on this topic. Text, email, snail mail, zoom etc. You really should have picked up the phone here.

What is your legal notice period? I may be wrong but I think 14 days is customary, not legally required, so no matter what the company does you may be able to leave after 14 days with zero notice.

To state the hopefully obvious: you should have done something about this before 23rd December; while people might be working today, you should not assume people are. By lunchtime on Friday at the very latest, you should have been getting in your manager's face and asking what's happening.
Now accepting that you didn't do that, you do the best you can. There doesn't seem to be a dispute that you've resigned or when your last working day is, so just be professional: keep working until that day. If you typically work in office, you can leave your laptop and any other company possessions with a trusted person as you walk out the door on the last day. If you typically work remotely, your employer was going to have arrange to have them picked up anyway, and they won't be too bothered if that happens today, on the 26th December or in the New Year. Message your manager, copying in HR, letting them know some contact details for you and that you will work with them to return their possessions.

If you aren't sure who a trusted person is, ask another manager if they could sign off on your having returned the equipment.
